# addEventListener with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in javascript (vanilla). I know how to do it in CSS, but i will never really understand Javascript if i don't try to do things in Javascript, hence the question.

My issue is that i cannot work out how to use the array from `getElementsByClassName` and loop it to target only the `<li>` that was clicked. I have googled until my head hurts, This is due to a lack of understanding/knowledge on how to get/use arrays with an `onclick` event with a loop. If someone could kindly help me out with this

```js
function startUp() {
    subMenu();
}

function subMenu() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('Menu').addEventListener('click', subMenu);
    var drop = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
        for (i = 0; i < drop.length; i++){
            drop += drop.length;
            if (drop.style.display === 'none') {
                drop.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }else {
                drop.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
}
window.onload = startUp;
```

```html
<nav id="Menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Members</li>
        <li>Gallery
            <ul class="sub" style="display: none;">
                <li>link</li>
                <li>link 1</li>
                <li>link 2</li>
                <li>link 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Contact
            <ul class="sub" style="display: none;">
                <li>E-Mail</li>     
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Steam Community</li>
        <li>Youtube</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have tried multiple different variations of code all afternoon, I just cannot seem to get it all to work together, without writing multiple functions for ID's instead of using classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drop` is a `nodeList` which represents elements with `sub` class.

Every element from `drop` can be accessed using its `index`. => `drop[i]`

```
for (i = 0; i < drop.length; i++){
        //process drop[i]
}
```

I recommend you to use follow method:

You need to attach a `click` event for every `li` with `sub` class. The problem is that when `subMenu` function is invoked, it is created a single `context`. If you don't use `let` keywork, you'll see that you receive error because when you click `li` item, last value of `i` in for loop will be `2` in this case. This is an usual problem. Please take a look here : [closures inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). For this type of problem, ECMS6 offers `let` keyword.

```js
function startUp() {
    subMenu();
}

function subMenu() {
    var drop = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
    for(let i=0;i<drop.length;i++){
        drop[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
          if(drop[i].querySelector('ul').style.display==='none'){
            drop[i].querySelector('ul').style.display='block';
          }
          else
            drop[i].querySelector('ul').style.display='none';
        });
    };
}
window.onload = startUp;
```

```html
<nav id="Menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Members</li>
        <li class="sub">Gallery
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>link</li>
                <li>link 1</li>
                <li>link 2</li>
                <li>link 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub">Contact
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>E-Mail</li>     
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Steam Community</li>
        <li>Youtube</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you don't want to use `let` keyword, you should use [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

If you want to `select` the links without the whole menu closing again, you have to use `event.target` property, which indicates the DOM element that initiated the event. Thus, you apply `toggle` event only when you are clicking the `li` with `sub` class and not `ul` childrens.

```js
function startUp() {
    subMenu();
}

function subMenu() {
   var drop = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
   for(var i=0;i<drop.length;i++){
     (function(index){
         drop[index].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            if(e.target.className=="sub"){
                if(drop[index].querySelector('ul').style.display==='none'){
                   drop[index].querySelector('ul').style.display='block';
                }
                else
                   drop[index].querySelector('ul').style.display='none';
            }
         });
     })(i);   
    };
}
window.onload = startUp;
```

```html
<nav id="Menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Members</li>
        <li class="sub">Gallery
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>link</li>
                <li>link 1</li>
                <li>link 2</li>
                <li>link 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub">Contact
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>E-Mail</li>     
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Steam Community</li>
        <li>Youtube</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have edited my code to follow this, However it works wherever i click on the Nav bar, and it drops both sub-menus at the same time, Is there a way to do this with only one displaying at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors!

```
function startUp() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('Menu');//Set handler here
    menu.addEventListener('click', subMenu);
    subMenu();
}

function subMenu() {

    var drop = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
        for (i = 0; i < drop.length; i++){
            drop += drop.length; //???? drop it is array of htmlElements if you want get one elemnt use drop[i];
            if (drop.style.display === 'none') {
                drop.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }else {
                drop.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
}
window.onload = startUp;
```